# Opencart как сделать такой вид валюты?

Tags: opencart

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать что бы валюта добавляла пробел после тыс. 
К примеру сейчас цена показывается вот так `2728.33` ( 33 это копейки )

А хотелось бы `2 728.33`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняется в основном файле локализации, например, catalog\language\ru-ru\ru-ru.php
.Переменная `$_['thousand_point'] = ' ';` отвечает за разделитель разрядов.